# How to create deb that install another deb before installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, deb, dpkg

I want to create .deb file that could be installed on a out-of-box Ubuntu.

I have prepeared control, preinst, postinst files. But when I try to install my package on a fresh Ubuntu it says that "Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock". I know that it is a common problem when people want to install different software at the same time. But how do I install python3-pip and nginx?

Sure, I can create 2 files: mysofr.deb and install.sh. But the point is to have only one file, so user could install my soft with only one command.

Here is my preinst:

```
dpkg -s "python3-pip" >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
    echo "python3-pip is installed."
    echo
  } || {
    echo "ERROR: python3-pip is not installed. Now it will be installed from default repo"
#    rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
#    dpkg --configure -a
    sudo apt install python3-pip
  }
```

As you can see, I have tried to unlock dpkg. But it was a bad idea to do it during installation.

Here is my postinst:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd *directory*
dpkg -i nginx_1.14.2-1_stretch_amd64.deb
rm nginx_1.14.2-1_stretch_amd64.deb
systemctl enable nginx
service nginx start
```

In short: I want to create deb that could check if there is a python3-pip and nginx and if there is no such software - install it: nginx from .deb file, python3-pip from default repo.

Comment: Be declarative instead of imperative: do not install dependencies yourself — declare dependencies in package metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare these dependencies in the control file, as Depends. See the documentation on those fields in `man deb-control`.

Installing from within the maintainer scripts is completely unsupported and trying to force that via the removal of the lock file is going to damage the dpkg database or the installation, don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

if you get comments like that, it means that before you cancel the installation, for this problem you can use the following command "$rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock",

Comment: Never remove the dpkg lock file. That will surely lead to dpkg database and system damage. The dpkg lock file is range based not existence based, removing it is never the correct answer. See https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_can_be_done_when_the_dpkg_lock_is_held.3F